# how to indicate the user to activate the internet in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to add this feature in Facebook Lite to the Flutter application, where this message appears when the Internet is cut off?
See the image below [show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hgejp.jpg)

**
Addition :
Suggest me to add the package [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)
But Can this package know if Wi-Fi or data are activated, but there is no internet, so the message that there is no internet appears?

Comment: With [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package you can check internet is connected or not. If its not connected then You can display dialog box of Internet is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

Import [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) package and use below code.

```
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'dart:io';

var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.mobile && connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  //Internet is not connected
} else {
  // Internet is connected

 try {
   final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
   if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
     print('connected');
   }
 } on SocketException catch (_) {
   print('not connected');
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks but Can this package know if Wi-Fi or data are activated, but there is no internet, so the message that there is no internet appears?

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can use that. It will also check if wifi is connected but there is no internet.

Answer (score 0):

With this package https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

```
var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        showDialog();
    }
```

or you setup a listener and watch yor connectivitiy changes

```
 subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    // Got a new connectivity status!
  })
```

Comment: thanks but Can this package know if Wi-Fi or data are activated, but there is no internet, so the message that there is no internet appears?